# App Crash in Production - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter app, only Android 9 (SDK 28) got some crash report. I have used following plugin
'''

```
 firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
 firebase_auth_web: ^0.3.2
 firebase_core_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
 firebase_core: ^0.5.3
 firebase_auth_oauth: ^0.2.2
 firebase_auth_oauth_web: ^0.2.1
 firebase_storage: ^5.0.1

java.lang.NullPointerException: 
 at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.lambda$null$1 (FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java:25)
 at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.lambda$null$1$FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin (FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java)
 at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.-$$Lambda$FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin$68gQDwhbF_O239JRWHIUWKRjjiU.onIdTokenChanged (-.java:4)
 at com.google.firebase.auth.zzi.run (zzi.java:4)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:907)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzj.dispatchMessage (zzj.java)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)

Error came in Production release
```

Comment: You know how to read a stack trace don't you? Look for "... caused by."

Comment: this crash details get from play store console